# error while using 'cv.ncvreg'

Tags: r

When I use 'cv.ncvreg' (from the `ncvreg` package) to do penalized estimation via SCAD, an error occurs sometimes and terminates my for loop:

```
library(spls)
library(ncvreg)
data("lymphoma")
x.m = lymphoma$x
y.v = lymphoma$y
y.v[y.v==2]=1
x.m = x.m[,sample(1:ncol(x.m),1000)]

tserr = rep(0,1000)
for(iter in 1:1000){
  id<-sample(1:length(y.v),0.67*length(y.v))
  trx<-x.m[id,];try<-y.v[id]
  tsx<-x.m[-id,];tsy<-y.v[-id]
  scad.fit = cv.ncvreg(X=trx, y=try, family="binomial", penalty="SCAD", nfolds = 3)
  opt.lam = scad.fit$lambda[which.min(scad.fit$cve)]
  final.fit = ncvreg(X=trx, y=try, family="binomial", penalty="SCAD", lambda=opt.lam)
  p.vec = cbind(1,tsx) %*% coef(final.fit)
  class.pred = (exp(p.vec) / (1+exp(p.vec))) > 0.5
  tserr[iter] = mean(abs(class.pred - tsy))
}
## Error in dimnames(beta) <- list(varnames, lamNames(lambda)) : 
##   length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
## In addition: There were 25 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

The package works very well with other datasets (like leukemia, breast cancer ...)

However, there's something wrong with `lymphoma`. :(

What's the problem with `cv.ncvreg()` and `lymphoma`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate this, but I'm going to answer with some debugging tips that will be easier to read here than in a comment:

- it's helpful to include the results of `sessionInfo()` (or at least your operating system and the package versions you're using) in your question
- if you add `cat(iter,"\n")` to your loop code you can see at which iteration your code failed.
- if you add `set.seed(101)` to the top of your code (before the first command you use that calls the random-number generator) it will produce (more) reproducible results
- if you further add `set.seed(1000+iter)` to your loop code, then when you figure out that the code failed on the (e.g.) 745th iteration, you can use `set.seed(1745)` to go straight to that iteration so that you can more easily see what happened
- alternately you can use `options(error=recover)` to have R dump you into a debugging environment when an error occurs
- or, if you don't mind simply skipping an occasional run that would produce errors, you can wrap the problematic functions in `try()` and do something appropriate if it failed, e.g. `final.fit <- try(<your code here>); if (inherits(final.fit,"try-error")) next`